# What is the correct way to set up FTP on a Multisite Webserver

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, ftp, vsftpd

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 as a webserver with multiple websites. I want to grant users FTPS access to certain directories in order to administer the website. I have the directories for multiple sites set up as normal -

```
/var/www/htdocs/website1
/var/www/htdocs/website2
```

I've installed vsftpd using this guide :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-vsftpd-to-use-ssl-tls-on-an-ubuntu-vps

but instead of setting up the user as specified in the guide I added user1 to the **www-data** group. I've chroot'ed that users home directory to the individual sites directory.

So here's my question, I know the next step would be to **chmod** the directory and it's contents to allow **rwx** for the **www-data** group but I'm not sure if that is the proper way of doing it from a security point of view. What are the implications of setting things that way and is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: chmod to allow access to the individual user, while allowing r-x rights for the group

Comment: Why don't you just use SFTP instead?

Comment: What's the benefit over SFTP over FTPS? I was just using FTPS for the learning experience but am open to suggestions

The group already has r-x access. Do you have a chmod example for an individual user? Wouldn't I have to chown for that?

Comment: @mactire SFTP uses the same credentials and ACLs as SSH.  You do not need to set anything else up.  You just need an SFTP client, which works very much the same way as an FTP client.

Comment: For shared hosting, you need to consider more than just FTP. If your webserver executes PHP or whatnot as `www-data` (group) and every directory is readable or even writable by `www-data`, everyone can read (or even write) each others data. Unfortunately, there’s no painless solution.

Comment: @DanielB That's exactly what im concerned about. I didn't want to change www-data permissions. I was hoping to leave www-data:www-data as the owner of all within /www/var/ also but im open to suggestions

Also I went with FTPS initially because I didn't want to open SSH externally to begin with either

Answer (score 2):

The best option here would be to uninstall ftp and use sftp only. It's easy to use and highly secure (military-grade secure). ACL of the wwwdoc folder needs to be setup in a way that user can write to it and change containing files/folders ownership. To connect to the server, make users use SFTP client (sftp or scp command for Linux users, WinSCP for Windows users).

Comment: `scp` is not a SFTP client.

Comment: It's not, but can be used as one.

Comment: No, it can’t. It uses the SCP protocol. It uses SSH as well but is completely different from SFTP.